# Adjusting the width of a Jekyll code block

Tags: html, css, jekyll

In my Jekyll theme I can add code snippets to my markdown posts using:

```
{% highlight ruby %}
def print_hi(name)
  puts "Hi, #{name}"
end
print_hi('Tom')
#=> prints 'Hi, Tom' to STDOUT.
{% endhighlight %}
```

however the width is too narrow on mobile devices. I am trying to increase the width using css like so in `_site.scss`:

```
  figure {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This gives the desired with not however the code block is not centered. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by `width is too narrow`. Are you talking about carrier's width?

Comment: Try with `overflow-x: scroll`